# How to get the option of changing the currency in frontend area?

Tags: magento2

[image]
I basically want a drop-down menu to appear in frontend that would allow customers to switch between different currencies that I have selected as "Allowed Currencies" in the admin area. I don't necessarily want it in the header.

Comment: where do you mean by front? the site landing page? that drop down is part of header so that it can be visible on all pages while customers are shopping.

Comment: In frontend area. If it comes in header, that's fine as well. I've made the necessary changes to Admin(Selecting a Default Currency and multiple Allowed Currencies), so now I need an option to switch between the currencies to show up when someone access the main website.